# Custom Sort Order with Predicates

Tags: swift

I have an array

> arr = ["A", "B", "a", "b", "1", "2"]

When I sort it using:

```
arr.sorted(by: <)
```

I get:

> ["1", "2", "A", "B", "a", "b"]

But I am looking for the result:

> ["a", "b", "A", "B", "1", 2"]

Sort of a custom sort order where smalls come first in sorted order then caps in sorted order and then numbers in sorted order. 
What is an easy way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might be wrong but I think you will need to implement your own custom sorting method:

```
var arr = ["A", "B", "a", "b", "1", "2"]
arr.sort {
    if $0.first?.isLowercase == true && ($1.first?.isUppercase == true || $1.first?.isWholeNumber == true) {
        return true
    }
    if $0.first?.isUppercase == true && $1.first?.isWholeNumber == true {
        return true
    }
    if $0.first?.isWholeNumber == true && ($1.first?.isLowercase == true ||  $1.first?.isUppercase == true) {
        return false
    }
    return $0 < $1
}

print(arr) // "["a", "b", "A", "B", "1", "2"]\n"
```

---

```
extension MutableCollection where Element: StringProtocol, Self: RandomAccessCollection {
    mutating func customSort(by areInIncreasingOrder: (Element, Element) throws -> Bool = (<)) rethrows {
        try sort {
            if try areInIncreasingOrder("1","2") {
                if $0.first?.isLowercase == true && ($1.first?.isUppercase == true || $1.first?.isWholeNumber == true) {
                    return true
                }
                if $0.first?.isUppercase == true && $1.first?.isWholeNumber == true {
                    return true
                }
                if $0.first?.isWholeNumber == true && ($1.first?.isLowercase == true ||  $1.first?.isUppercase == true) {
                    return false
                }
            } else {
                if $0.first?.isWholeNumber == true && ($1.first?.isLowercase == true ||  $1.first?.isUppercase == true) {
                    return true
                }
                if $0.first?.isUppercase == true && ($1.first?.isLowercase == true || $1.first?.isWholeNumber == true) {
                    return true
                }
                if $0.first?.isLowercase == true && ($1.first?.isUppercase == true || $1.first?.isWholeNumber == true) {
                    return false
                }
            }
            return try areInIncreasingOrder($0,$1)
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
var array =  ["B","A","b", "a", "1", "2"]
do {
    try array.customSort()
    print(array) // "["a", "b", "A", "B", "1", "2"]\n"
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. It's perfect.